# Encoding Issue while using French in WordPress

Tags: encoding

I just migrated some content from another CMS [SPIP] into WordPress and I am seeing weird characters like ' UnitÃ© dans la diversitÃ© ', this is supposed to come in french but its not . Please let me know what can be done to convert this content into Unicode.

Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the Following bash script for the conversion from non unicode to utf-8

```
#!/bin/bash -e

DB_HOST="localhost"
DB_USER="username"
DB_PASSWORD="paassword"
DB_NAME="dbname"


mysqldump -h "$DB_HOST" -u "$DB_USER" - p"$DB_PASSWORD" --opt --quote-names -- skip-set-charset --default-character-set=latin1 "$DB_NAME" > /tmp/temp.sql;

mysql -h "$DB_HOST" -u "$DB_USER" - p"$DB_PASSWORD" --default-character- set=utf8 "$DB_NAME" < /tmp/temp.sql;
```

This did the job. I opened the DB in sublime text and the french characters were rendered correctly.

More information on this at https://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

Comment: This is a link only answer which is not constuctive to the site. Please add all relevant information from that link in an [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Try to change encoding rule to utf8 in your databse. This can easily be done with phpMyAdmin for example. If this does not solve your issue, add encoding attribue to your Html tag.

Hope this helps.